# Is it possible to sort a TDBGrid on a lookup field?

Tags: delphi

I have a DBGrid with a column based on a lookup field.

How can I set it up so that when a user clicks on the column title, it will sort by that field.

My problem here is that I can't figure out a way to create an index on a lookup field.

I'm using Absolute Database for this, but most things that work with the BDE or TClientDataSet will work with Absolute.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to create an index on a lookup field. It is possible to create an index on an internally calculated field of a ClientDataSet though. In the OnCalcFields event handler set its value to the value of the lookup field. And set the visible property of the lookup field to false. Now you can sort on the internally calculated field.

Comment: Since this is a lookup field, you will also want to add additional data to your calculated field for sorting purposes to uniquely identify each record.  This will avoid the problem of refreshes possibly changing the order of the records which are grouped by the same lookup value.

Answer (score 4):

What you could do (especially if the data is readonly, and does not have zillions of rows) is use a ClientDataSet to display data in your grid.

Roughly the steps would be like this:

1. Load the data from your regular into the ClientDataSet,
2. add a calculated field to the ClientDataSet that contains the value obtained from the lookup,
3. then add an index to that calculated
   field.

--jeroen

Answer (score 1):

You cannot sort by a lookup field. But you can 'fake' this. Let's suppose that you have the following tables: (PK means Primary Key)

### Contacts

- ID - Integer (PK)
- NAME - Varchar(40)
- COUNTRYID - Integer

### Countries

- ID - Integer (PK)
- NAME - Varchar(40)

Then you can have the following query in the dataset which is linked to the TDBGrid:

```
SELECT C.ID, C.NAME, C.COUNTRYID, CO.NAME 
FROM CONTACTS C
JOIN COUNTRIES CO ON C.COUNTRYID=CO.ID
```

(Not tested but I think that you got the idea)

Also you can put this in a view.

Then you'll display in your TDBGrid (as columns) *only* the ID, NAME and the desired lookup field which you already have (let's call it COUNTRYLOOK).

When one clicks on the Title Header you can change the query by adding in the 4th line an ORDER BY . For the specific column of the lookup field (COUNTRYLOOK), instead of using the 1:1 mapping you can put in the 4th line of your query ORDER BY CO.NAME. Reopen the query and that's it. In practice is much more simpler than my description here.

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress ExpressQuantumGrid can do it, check it out:
http://www.devexpress.com/products/vcl/exquantumgrid/